# What is the purpose of this web.config.transform file

Tags: c#

I've inherited an application from a collegue who has left the company and I've come across a file called web.config.transform. It contains the usual transformation syntax but is separate from the web.config file.

This obviously updates the config file but I wasn't aware one could have a separate file to do this.  What is the purpose of using a separate file versus using the usual web.debug.config and web.release.config?

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=web+config+transforms&oq=web+config+transforms&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2831j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple google provided many answers and examples however, MS wrote https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

In which it describes the file as the changes to the web.config that will be done on deployment, it is an alternative method to having two separate files of .debug and .release.  You could argue a file with all the settings and just updating datasources or endpoint addresses would be less prone to missing something on release.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: Well, if the fact that the file describes how to change a central file for deployment is not answering somehow, then the question must be unclear.  Whether you use this or the .debug or .release is personal preference..

Comment: including links is poor as you well know, but thank you for letting me know that you can either use the debug files or a central file.  I now know the answer and appreciate your help.  Perhaps if you update your answer to explain that i can mark it as answered

Comment: Links are not bad if you use from them so it is explained but more info is on the link

Comment: But you didnt explain

Comment: I did, the file describes the changes to web.config on deployment!

Comment: but that wasnt the question.  The question was "what is the purpose of having a seperate file" as i'd never seen it done like that.  You answered in your comment above so thank you.  Like i said if you update your answer i will mark it as answered.

Comment: is that better?